# Memory leak in Jetpack Compose - Mapbox

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, mapbox-android

Mapbox in Jetpack Compose takes up a lot of RAM. When I open the view that contains the map, the memory takes more and more each time I go into that view.

How can I destroy the memory When I left the view?

```
AndroidView(modifier = Modifier.height(240.dp).clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp)),
factory = {
        View.inflate(it, R.layout.main_mapview_mapbox, null)
        MapView(it).apply {
           mapView = this
           getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri("mapbox://styles/.../....") {sty ->
                trip.listOfLatLon.let { points ->
                val polygon = Polygon.fromLngLats(listOf(points))
                val cameraPosition = getMapboxMap().cameraForGeometry(polygon,padding =  
EdgeInsets(220.0, 320.0, 220.0, 320.0))

                val viewAnnotationManager = this.viewAnnotationManager
                viewAnnotationManager.addViewAnnotation(
                 R.layout.camera_report_annotation,
                 viewAnnotationOptions {
                   geometry(points[0])
                   allowOverlap(false)
                   anchor(ViewAnnotationAnchor.BOTTOM)
                   visible(true)
                }
               )
               viewAnnotationManager.addViewAnnotation(
                R.layout.police_report_annotation,
                viewAnnotationOptions {
                   geometry(points[trip.listOfLatLon.size - 1])
                    allowOverlap(false)
                    anchor(ViewAnnotationAnchor.CENTER)
                    visible(true)
                }
               )
              getMapboxMap().setCamera(cameraPosition)
            }
           var data = geoJsonSource("line") {
    featureCollection(FeatureCollection.fromFeature(feature))
            }
            sty.addSource(data)
            sty.addLayer(lineLayer("linelayer", "line") {
            lineCap(LineCap.ROUND)
            lineJoin(LineJoin.ROUND)
            lineWidth(4.0)
            lineColor("#495CE8")
           })
           }
           scalebar.enabled = false
           compass.enabled = false
           gestures.scrollEnabled = false
           gestures.pitchEnabled = false
         }
       })
   }
```

Comment: We have what seems to be the same issue with  'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.11.2'

Comment: You seem to be holding `mapView` somewhere else. Could you please share the full code?

Answer (score 0):

According to mapbox dev, it's fixed in v11.0.0-rc.2 c